# Java jframe freezing when running code in thread

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Im making a brute force program that can crack SHA1 codes. Im very new to using threads I want to use them to speed up the application by running in parallell. Can anyone help me and stop jframe freezing. the threads work and produce the correct answers but never allows me to use jframe again.

code im using for threads:

```
public class crack1 extends Thread {

    char[] pass1 = new char[1];

    public boolean crack11() {
        // while(!exit){

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

            pass1[0] = alpha1[i];
            if (compareit(input, pass1) == true) {

                System.out.println(String.valueOf("password =" + pass1[0]));
                return true;

            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean cracker(String input) {

        crack1 obj1 = new crack1();
        crack2 obj2 = new crack2();
        crack3 obj3 = new crack3();
        crack4 obj4 = new crack4();
        crack5 obj5 = new crack5();
        crack6 obj6 = new crack6();

        if (obj1.crack11() == true) {
            jTextArea1.append("password found");
            System.out.println("password found");
        }

        // obj2.run();
        // obj3.run();
        // obj4.run();
        // obj5.run();
        // obj6.run();

        System.out.println("done");

    }

    public static boolean compareit(String input, char[] test) {
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(test));

        String answer = String.valueOf(test);

        String check = sha1(String.valueOf(test));

        if (input.equals(check)) {
            // jTextArea1.append("password ="+answer);
            // System.out.println(String.valueOf("password ="+answer));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show me how you start the threads within your JFrame app. Normally a SWING app (and JFX as well) is only active after setVisible(true) or show() in JFX is executed

Answer (score 0):

```
//obj2.run();
```

That is not how you use a Thread. Invoking the run() method directly will just cause the code to execute on the current Thread.

To have the code execute on a separate Thread you need to use:

```
obj2.start();
```

Comment: perfect that fixed the thread issue but the jframe is still crashing any ideas?